# Web Services XML con despliegue en HTML

Tags: php, html, xml

```
$url = 'http://www.webservicex.net//country.asmx/GetCountries?';
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    $err = curl_error($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);

                    echo '<br><br>'.$result.'<br><br>';

            $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

            print_r($array);
```

En el Archivo HTML como debe de ir el Select?

Lista de Pais:

```
<select id="campoPais" name="campoPais">

</select>
```

para llamar los paises de la WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @Gabriel Díaz-Chirón Muñoz es la mejor forma, yo he intentado parsear dicha URL y no he sido capaz.

Te ofrezco una solucion un tanto "casera" pero que puede ayudarte a salir del paso.

Lo que recibes via Curl es un STRING con formato XML, si no consigues transformarlo a objeto puedes limpiar la cadena y explotarla.

```
    $url = 'http://www.webservicex.net//country.asmx/GetCountries?';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = substr($result, 114);
    $result = substr($result,0,- 30);
    $result = chop($result);
    $borra  = array("Table","Name","&lt;","&gt;","/");
    $output  = str_replace($borra, '', $result);
    $output = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);

    $i= 0;
    $pais = array();
    foreach ($output as $value) {
        if(strlen($value)>3){
            $pais[++$i] = $value;
        }
    }
    echo '<select id="campoPais" name="campoPais">';

    foreach ($pais as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, una consulta no he podido hacer el array para q me lo lea en el html,  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml);
    foreach($xml->Table as $table) 
    {
    $output .= "<p>$table->Name</p>";
    
    $value = (array) $table->Name;
      echo '<option value="'.strtolower($value[0]).'">'.$value[0].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
  print_r($output);

Comment: Una consulta de que manera le envio un parametro al Web Service GetAirportInfomationByCountry?? Estoy tratando de hacerlo con el mismo                   codigo de arriba!$url = http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?op=GetAirportInformationByCountry

Comment: Buenas, te he dejado mas abajo el codigo("Respuesta corta"), si tengo tiempo para algo mas elaborado te lo digo @danbf

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría es sacar el xml de la URL que comentas y transformarlo a objetos o array y hacer un bucle y pintar el select.

Este sería el código:

```
    $paisesXML = file_get_contents('http://www.webservicex.net//country.asmx/GetCountries?');
    $paisesXML = simplexml_load_string($paisesXML);
    $paises = new SimpleXMLElement($paisesXML);
    echo '<select name="campoPais" id="campoPais">';
        foreach ($paises as $pais) {
            $value = (array) $pais->Name;
            echo '<option value="'.strtolower($value[0]).'">'.$value[0].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Te entiendo pero esto iria despues de este codigo:  $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

            print_r($array);   O ESTE YA NO VA EXISTIR? y en el html no pondria nada? gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: no es necesario que lo pongas después lo que he puesto valdría ya para obtener todo. Y los echo pintaría en el html dinamicamente. Yo he puesto echo pero podrías usar los $value como tu quisieras :)

Comment: Listo muchas gracias :D

Comment: Una consulta de que manera le envio un parametro al Web Service GetAirportInfomationByCountry?? Estoy tratando de hacerlo con el mismo                   codigo de arriba!$url = http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?op=GetAirportInformationByCountry

Comment: Por ejemplo si quieres los de España: http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx/GetAirportInformationByCountry?country=spain

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta:

Sustituye 'spain' por el país del select anterior

```
  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx/GetAirportInformationByCountry");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "country=spain");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$paisesXML = simplexml_load_string($server_output);
$paises = new SimpleXMLElement($paisesXML);
    echo '<select name="campoPais" id="campoPais">';
        foreach ($paises as $pais) {
            $value = (array) $pais->CityOrAirportName;
            echo '<option value="'.strtolower($value[0]).'">'.$value[0].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
```